# Add system images to android sdk manager in visual studio 2022 manually

Tags: android, android-emulator, visual-studio-2022, android-sdk-manager

I want to add system images to android sdk manager manually in visual studio 2022, because downloading it by sdk manager is very time-consuming due to the low internet speed and international internet restrictions in Iran.
Note that system images are saved in "Users[user].android\avd" and some configurations must be made to system image files to become usable, such as editing config.ini file in system image folder.
Thank you.